# Displaying data from an JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have to program a php where i display data of people from a JSON file . The default view shows just the names of the persons. If i click on one of the elements the view should change to the full informations of the clicked person ,so then the name ,phinenumber and email.

My problem is that i can't figure out how to change the view from one to the other

so this is what i have so far

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="skript.js"></script>
    <title>Main</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Main</h1>
    </header>
    
    
    </nav>
    <main class="view">
        
    </main>     
</body>

</html>
```

// js

```
fetch('data.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => createListContact(data));

/**
* Function to display as a list data.json
*/
function createListContact(data) {
    // create ol for all persons
      const ol = document.createElement('ol');
      ol.classList.add("list-view");

      // for each person one li 
      for (let i = 0; i < data.personen.length; i++) {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.classList.add("button");
        li.setAttribute("id", i+1);
        li.innerHTML ='Name: '+ data.personen[i].nachname + ', ' + data.personen[i].vorname;
        
        ol.appendChild(li);
          document.body.appendChild(ol);
        
        }
        
}
       
/*
* Function adds event listener to li element
*/
function eventListener (){
  const liElements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

   for (let li of liElements){
       li.addEventListener("click",() => showDetails(li));
   }
}

/** 
*  Function to open detailed info
*
*   @param li element to show details from
*/
  function showDetails(li){
    var details = document.createElement('div');
    details.className = 'details';
    details.id ="test";

    var close = document.createElement('div');
    close.className= 'close';
    close.innerHTML= 'close';
    close.onclick = function(e) { details.parentNode.removeChild(details)};
    var info = document. createElement('li');
    info.innerHTML = 'Name: '+ data.personen[i].nachname + ', ' + data.personen[i].vorname +
    'Tel.: '+ data.personen[i].telefonnummer+
    'E-mail: '+data.personen[i].email;
    details.appendChild(info);
    details.appendChild(schließen);
    document.body.appendChild(details);

    
  }
```

// css

```
body {
  background-color: #886b6b77;
}       
p {
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
textarea
{
    font-family: inherit;    
}

form {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1em;

}

form label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: darkslategrey;
    padding-left: 3px;    
    
}

input,
textarea
{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.1em; 
    padding: 4px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: lighter;
    border:1px solid gray;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
}    

input:focus,
textarea:focus { 
    border:1px solid orange;
}

input[type=submit] {
   background-color: #ffffff77;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 14em;
    padding: .3em 0;
    border-radius: 0.7em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: rgb(59, 58, 58);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px grey;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ol{
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
img{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
#wahl{
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
#button_load{
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

/*
* list-view
*/
.list-view .button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.list-view .button:hover{
  background-color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just append the JSON data to the  DOM element (`<li>`) itself: `li.personData = person;` where `person` is the object that contains name etc. And then it is easy to get a hold of the data when you need to show details (`e.target.personData` has the object).

I also moved the eventlistener to the ordered list element (`<ol>`). Then you just need to test if it was a list element that the user clicked.

```js
fetch('data:application/json;base64,eyJwZXJzb25lbiI6Clt7Im5hY2huYW1lIjoiTmFjaG5hbWUgMSIsCiJ2b3JuYW1lIjogIlZvcm5hbWUgMSJ9LAp7Im5hY2huYW1lIjoiTmFjaG5hbWUgMiIsCiJ2b3JuYW1lIjogIlZvcm5hbWUgMiJ9XX0=')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => createListContact(data));

/**
 * Function to display as a list data.json
 */
function createListContact(data) {
  document.querySelector('main.view').innerHTML = "";
  // create ol for all persons
  const ol = document.createElement('ol');
  ol.classList.add("list-view");
  ol.addEventListener("click", showDetails);

  // for each person one li
  data.personen.forEach((person, i) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add("button");
    li.setAttribute("id", `person_${i}`);
    li.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + person.nachname + ', ' + person.vorname;
    li.personData = person;

    ol.appendChild(li);
  });
  document.querySelector('main.view').append(ol);
}

/** 
 *  Function to open detailed info
 *
 *   @param li element to show details from
 */
function showDetails(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName == 'LI') {
    var details = document.createElement('div');
    details.className = 'details';
    details.id = "test";

    var close = document.createElement('div');
    close.className = 'close';
    close.innerHTML = 'close';
    close.addEventListener('click', e => {
      details.parentNode.removeChild(details);
    });

    var info = document.createElement('li');
    info.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + e.target.personData.nachname + ', ' + e.target.personData.vorname +
      'Tel.: ' + e.target.personData.telefonnummer +
      'E-mail: ' + e.target.personData.email;
    details.append(info);
    details.append(close);
    document.body.append(details);
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #886b6b77;
}

p {
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

form label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: darkslategrey;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

input,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 4px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: lighter;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #ffffff77;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 14em;
  padding: .3em 0;
  border-radius: 0.7em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: rgb(59, 58, 58);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px grey;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}


/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#wahl {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

#button_load {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}


/*
* list-view
*/

.list-view .button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.list-view .button:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Main</h1>
</header>
<main class="view">
</main>
```

Comment: how would i add and remove one person from the data?  i know i can use push and splice but i don't know how to get access to the data.